# How do I specify the path to node in SublimeText3 for Sublime-JSHint plugin in Windows

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint

After installing node.js then the Sublime-JSHint plugin on Windows XP with SublimeText3, I get the following error:

"Node.js was not found in the default path. Please specify the location."

This is a known configuration issue and is documented by the author, however I can't work out how to specify the path. Can anyone tell me how to specify the path in Windows XP?

https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-JSHint#oh-noez-command-not-found

I have tried

```
"node_path": "/Program Files/nodejs",

"node_path": "C:/Program Files/nodejs",

"node_path": "/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",

"node_path": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",
```

Comment: If the file path of the HTML file contains non-sacii character ,then Sublime will prompt "Node.js was not found in the default path. Please specify the location."https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify/issues/126

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

"node_path": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe"

Comment: Thank you, remembering to add `node.exe` did the trick for me as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
"node_path": "/c/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe"
```

and make sure this option is in your `Packages/User/JSHint.sublime-settings` file. I'm not sure why your last setting didn't work, because it is also in a valid format, but hopefully using the Cygwin-style path will work.

Comment: This looked promising but I'm still getting the same error. I tried creating Packages/User/JSHint.sublime-settings, but whenever I get the error, clicking OK opens Packages/JSHint Gutter/JSHint.sublime-settings. I have tried commenting out the node_path line within that file and also deleting it altogether. Thanks for trying though

Comment: @plainflavour here's another option - adding the path to node to your Windows `PATH` variable. Right-click on My Computer, select Properties, go to the Advanced tab, click on the Environment Variable button, then find the PATH variable and click Edit. Go to the very end of what's already there, and after the last entry add `;C:\Program Files\nodejs` (make sure to include the `;`). Click OK, then restart Sublime and see if it works now...

Comment: Hi thanks again for your help. I've tried this, but still no use. I've also reinstalled node and the JSHint plugin but I guess it just doesn't work in XP.

Comment: That sucks. If it's any consolation, [SublimeLinter3](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3) is well on its way towards being released for ST3, and it includes (or included) JSHint by default. If you absolutely need it, and can't find another plugin, you could always downgrade to Sublime Text 2 and use [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter)...

Comment: Great, I'll look  out for that. Hopefully I'll get a new computer before that though!

Comment: I also found that changing the path and saving the config required a restart of sublime.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me:

```
"node_path": "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/node.exe\"",
```

I'm on Windows 7, so node was installed in Program Files (x86). Just knock of the " (x86)" part for if node is installed in Program Files.

I basically had to start the `cmd` application in Windows and type in commands until I found one that spit out the Node help text:

```
"c:/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/node.exe" --help
```

I had to encase the file path in double quotes because the file path had space characters and parenthesis in it. The `"node_path"` config setting also needed the file path encased in double quotes, which had to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I found an another issue that causes to show that error. Its on registry editor . HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor here I set AutoRun key to load c:\profile.bat where I added sublime path run sublime from cmd. But when I open cmd its through error ( its actually done by powershell ). After deleting that key node.js path working just fine. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with html-css-js.prettify.  In the end none of these issues worked for me and I had to comment out line 58-62 of HTMLPrettify.py so that the only line left would look up the path with the line...

```
node = settings.get("node_path")
```

I restarted SublimeText and it started working.

I imagine a similar solution might work for JSHint.

Answer (score 0):

I just change in the python script and asign my node path to node_path instead of get_node_path(). Or you can set `get_node_path()` to return `C:\\DevTools\\nodejs\\node.exe`

```
%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\HTML-CSS-JS Prettify\HTMLPrettify.py

line 81  def run_script_on_file(self, temp_file_path):
    try:
      node_path = "C:\\DevTools\\nodejs\\node.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should

```
Ctrl + ` // or View => Show Console
```

to see what's wrong.

Mostly, it's not the Node.js path problem

For example, what I could see is

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, I searched it, and solved it with:

```
// HTMLPrettify.py
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
# file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.

import sublime, sublime_plugin
import os, sys, subprocess, codecs, webbrowser

reload(sys) # NEW LINE !!! <================
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") # NEW LINE !!! <================
```

Well, after that, it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this setting DOES NOT work

```
"node_path": "/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v6.11.0/bin/node",
```

but this WORKS

```
"node_path": { "linux" : "/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v6.11.0/bin/node" }
```

This change has to be made in the **JSHint.sublime-settings** file.

Hope this helps! Although changes are effective right away, I would try restarting the Sublime after the change to make sure if this resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
I searched 'node.exe' in both program files and program files(x86).
Then I got a file named node.exe in some folder I copied its path and pasted like this

```
/path/node.exe
```

Note: you have to change `\` to `/`